# android adapter listview, changes to a row

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView holding items, and one of the items is highlighted.

When they click on a item i want the highlighted card to no longer be highlighted and the new item to be highlighted.

What I have done so far.

I call the adapter with a list, and one of the items in the list is defaultItem, which is true or false.

The when the getView gets called, I have an if defaultItem, and i make a change to that items's UI.  I also save that item in class variable called currentDefaultItem.

Now When they click I am able to change the list so that the old highlighted item to false and the clicked item to true.  I then call         notifyDataSetChanged();
however this doesn't seem to work.

The show getView

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    Card card = getItem(position);
    if (v == null) {
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_cards, parent, false);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.tvBrand = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvBrand);
    holder.tvLastFour = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvLastFour);
    holder.tvCounter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCounter);
    holder.tvCard = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCard);
        holder.arrow = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.arrow);
        holder.tick = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tick);

        if (card.getDefaultcard().intValue()==(1)){
            holder.tick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            positionOfDefault=position;
        }


        String brand = card.getBrand();
        switch (brand.toLowerCase()){
            case "visa":
                holder.tvCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.visa2);
                break;
            case "mastercard":
                holder.tvCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.mastercardx2);
                break;
            case "diners":
                holder.tvCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.dinersclub2);
                break;
            case "amex":
                holder.tvCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.americanexpress2);
                break;
            case "jcb":
                holder.tvCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.jcg2);
                break;
            case "discover":
                holder.tvCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.discover);
                break;
        }

    holder.b_delete_in_list = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.b_delete_in_list);

    holder.b_delete_in_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            deleteCard(position);
        }
    });
        holder.b_set_default = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.b_set_default);

        holder.b_set_default.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                updatePaymentMethod(position);
            }
        });
    //
    v.setTag(holder);

    //
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
}
    holder.tvName.setText(cardList.get(position).getName().toUpperCase());
    holder.tvBrand.setText(cardList.get(position).getBrand().toUpperCase());
    holder.tvLastFour.setText(cardList.get(position).getLast_four_digits());


    return v;
}
```

Comment: Paste code from getView method in adapter.

Comment: okay edited question

Comment: where is the currentDefaultItem variable ?

Comment: for simplicity sake i changed some of the names when explaining, defaultItem is defaultCard and it isn't a boolean but an int either equal to 1 or 0

Comment: Does your values changed on click ? did you have check it properly ?

Comment: @AdamKatz the if block where you are checking v==null should only contain the findViewById methods because this block will be executed only once and next time it will go to the else method. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    Card card = getItem(position);
    if (v == null) 
    {
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_cards, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.tvBrand = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvBrand);
        holder.tvLastFour = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvLastFour);
        holder.tvCounter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCounter);
        holder.tvCard = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCard);
        holder.arrow = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.arrow);
        holder.tick = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tick);

        v.setTag(holder);
     } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
     }

     if (card.getDefaultcard().intValue()==(1))
     {
            holder.tick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            positionOfDefault=position;
     }
     String brand = card.getBrand();
     switch (brand.toLowerCase()){
            case "visa":
                holder.tvCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.visa2);
                break;
            case "mastercard":
                holder.tvCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.mastercardx2);
                break;
            case "diners":
                holder.tvCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.dinersclub2);
                break;
            case "amex":
                holder.tvCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.americanexpress2);
                break;
            case "jcb":
                holder.tvCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.jcg2);
                break;
            case "discover":
                holder.tvCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.discover);
                break;
        }

    holder.b_delete_in_list = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b_delete_in_list);

    holder.b_delete_in_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            deleteCard(position);
        }
    });
        holder.b_set_default = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.b_set_default);

        holder.b_set_default.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                updatePaymentMethod(position);
            }
        });
    holder.tvName.setText(cardList.get(position).getName().toUpperCase());
    holder.tvBrand.setText(cardList.get(position).getBrand().toUpperCase());
    holder.tvLastFour.setText(cardList.get(position).getLast_four_digits());


    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your else statement is not updating the views. With Adapters your view will load up the maximum amount of items that fit on the screen those will be null so it hits the first if statement because the begining views are null. then once you update those views are no longer null. so then you have to change the View properties on the else statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your code which is managing default item:

```
    if (card.getDefaultcard().intValue()==(1)){
        holder.tick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        positionOfDefault=position;
    }
```

Must be in else not in **if (view==null )** because code in **if (view==null)** runs only ones, so when You change default your code never runs again.